# Issues while Creating an entity connection from a SQL Connection

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlconnection

We are converting our DB access to use Azure Identity with EF. I tried various different methods and failed because EF is expecting a model to be created and passed into the connection string which i was unable to do with DBConnection.
Finally I found a way to create the EntityConnection from a SQLConnection so I can retain all the information from the original connection string and add the metadata as needed. Here's my code:

```
public static EntityConnection GetEntityConnectionString( string efConnectionString, string accessToken )
        {
            MetadataWorkspace workspace = new MetadataWorkspace( new string[] { "res://*/" }, new Assembly[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() } );
                        
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection( efConnectionString );
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
            EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection( workspace, sqlConnection );
            return entityConnection;
        }
```

When I run this and get to the

```
EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection( workspace, sqlConnection );
```

I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'MetadataWorkspace must have EdmItemCollection pre-registered.'
```

Not sure what to do at this point and would really appreciate any insight that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, here's what I had to do to resolve the issue. I had to Register each individual Item Collection that is a part of the workspace.

```
public static EntityConnection GetEntityConnectionString( string efConnectionString, string accessToken )
        {

            MetadataWorkspace workspace = new MetadataWorkspace( new string[] { metadata[0] }, new Assembly[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() } );

            var edmItemCollection = new EdmItemCollection( "res://*/<filename>.csdl" );
            var store = new StoreItemCollection( "res://*/<filename>.ssdl" );
            var mapping = new StorageMappingItemCollection( edmItemCollection, store, "res://*/<filename>.msl" );


            workspace.RegisterItemCollection( edmItemCollection );
            workspace.RegisterItemCollection( store );
            workspace.RegisterItemCollection( mapping );
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection( efConnectionString );
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
            EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection( workspace, sqlConnection );
            return entityConnection;
        }
```